# How to decide which results to cache while bulding search in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an API for mobile frontend which has a search feature. Users search for articles. The back-end already has a keywords stored in Mysql. What would be the best strategy for caching so as to minimize the turnaround time.

Currently, I follow these steps:

1. Sanitize query.
2. Tokenize query.
3. Search for similar keywords with `LIKE` (Cache for `m` minutes)
4. Find Articles having above keywords (not sure if I should cache this result.)
5. `Order by Popularity`
6. Serve results.

**Does Laravel cache results based on query skeleton or complete query with parameters?**